# Trying to pass a hash map as a prop to another file in react

Tags: reactjs, hashmap, react-props, react-leaflet

I am calling that fetches certain values which I have placed in a hashmap, but these values simple wont pass props to the other component in another file. These are coordinates that I will mark on a map.

```
const Locate = (props) => {
  const { prop2 } = props;
  const BingMapsKey =
    "Ag5MTaRF5SQ60obFRwvV49z7E2Lrd_0z07itxeSOy474ghVEy0gK0blMuKtcqd_l";

  const [theHashTable, setTheHashTable] = useState(new Map());

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const encodedQuery = encodeURIComponent(prop2);

        const response = await axios.get(
          `https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/LocalSearch/?query=${encodedQuery}&userLocation=40.7128,-74.0064&key=${BingMapsKey}`
        );

        const place = response.data.resourceSets[0]?.resources;

        const newHashTable = new Map();

        place.forEach((resource) => {
          const { name, Address, PhoneNumber, Website } = resource;
          const [lat, long] = resource.point.coordinates;
          const key = `${lat},${long}`;
          newHashTable.set(key, {
            name,
            address: Address?.formattedAddress || "",
            phoneNumber: PhoneNumber || "",
            website: Website || "",
          });
        });

        setTheHashTable(newHashTable);
        console.log("Coordinates Hashtable:", newHashTable);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, [prop2]);

  return (
    <div>
          {console.log("The values: ", typeof (theHashTable))}
      <MapView propA={theHashTable} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Locate;
```

the code for the maps from leaflet.js is below:

```
import { MapContainer, TileLayer } from 'react-leaflet';
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
import biz from "./QnA/data.json" 
import axios from 'axios';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { json } from 'react-router-dom';
import React from 'react';



// eslint-disable-next-line react/display-name
const MapView = ({propA}) => {
  return (
    <div className="border-5 border-[#F2F7F6] bg-transparent rounded-3xl w-[150rem] flex items-center justify-content">
      <MapContainer
        center={[40.7128, -74.006]}
        zoom={13}
        style={{ height: "100%", width: "300%" }}
        className="rounded-3xl">
        <TileLayer url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png" />
      </MapContainer>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MapView;
```

I tried to set the code in the Locate component to a new function and tried to import that, but somehow the value in console was always undefined. Any help would be great.

Comment: Show the debug logs

Comment: `code`Submitted. Start: Central Park End: Bakery
Locate.jsx:159 The values:  object
Locate.jsx:159 The values:  object
Locate.jsx:148 Coordinates Hashtable: Map(10) {'40.71357346,-74.00836945' => {…}, '40.71917343,-73.99702454' => {…}, '40.71771622,-74.00447083' => {…}, '40.72507095,-74.00302887' => {…}, '40.71675873,-74.00652313' => {…}, …}
Locate.jsx:148 Coordinates Hashtable: Map(10) {'40.71357346,-74.00836945' => {…}, '40.71917343,-73.99702454' => {…}, '40.71771622,-74.00447083' => {…}, '40.72507095,-74.00302887' => {…}, '40.71675873,-74.00652313' => {…}, …}
I hope this is readable.